# NullPointerException possibly related to DataSource connection

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, datasource

I am attempting to use connection pooling for the first time in a web application. Currently I get this stacktrace when I attempt to load the home webpage which displays 2 testimonials retrieved from a MySQL database:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     uk.co.morleys.TestimonialService.getTestimonials(TestimonialService.java:57)
>     uk.co.morleys.HomeController.doGet(HomeController.java:54)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)

This error relates to the following method:

```
public class TestimonialService {
    ResultSet rs;

    public TestimonialService(){
        rs = null;
    }
    public List<Testimonial> getTestimonials(int limit) throws SQLException{
        List<Testimonial> list = new ArrayList<Testimonial>();
        DataSource dd = DataSourceFactory.getMySQLDataSource();

        try(Connection con = dd.getConnection()){
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id, author, testimonial, date FROM morleys_testimonial WHERE isActive=1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?");
            ps.setInt(1, limit);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                Testimonial Testimonial = new Testimonial();
                Testimonial.setAuthor(rs.getString("author"));
                Testimonial.setTestimonial(rs.getString("testimonial"));
                Testimonial.setDate(rs.getString("date"));
                Testimonial.setID(rs.getInt("id"));
                list.add(Testimonial);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is the DataDourceFactory class:

```
public class DataSourceFactory {

    public static DataSource getMySQLDataSource() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("db.properties");
            props.load(fis);
            mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();
            mysqlDS.setURL(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_URL"));
            mysqlDS.setUser(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
            mysqlDS.setPassword(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mysqlDS;
    }

}
```

and this is how I serve the home page to the browser:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String page = getPageName(request.getParameter("page"));
    switch (page){
            case "home":
                List<Testimonial> testimonialList;
                try {
                    testimonialList = testimonialService.getTestimonials(2);
                    request.setAttribute("testimonialList", testimonialList);
                } catch (SQLException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(views + getPageFilename(page));
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

**Question**
What is causing the `NullPointerException`. I am assuming it is something to do with the DataSource. Have I established a connection to the database correctly?

**UPDATE** Added `db.properties file

```
#mysql DB properties
MYSQL_DB_DRIVER_CLASS=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
MYSQL_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://myhostname/
MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=username
MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=password
```

[image: File structure]

Comment: Where do you init `rs`?

Comment: Which is line 57 of TestimonialService.java?

Comment: @juergend in the class constructor that contains the `getTestimonials()` method. I initialize it and give it a value of `null`.

Comment: line 57 is `try(Connection con = dd.getConnection()){`

Comment: What could possibly be null at this line except `dd`? Don't catch IOException and ignore it. Wrap the IOException into a runtime exception and throw it. Returning null from the getMySQLDataSource method is unacceptable, as it will, obviously cause NullPointerExceptions everywhere.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't understand why it is `null`. I'll add the `db.properties` file.

Comment: Read the stack trace of the IOException that has been printed to the standard error, and post it if you don't understand it. The stack trace tells you what and where the problem is. If you doidn't catch the exception and threw  it instead, it would be right in front of you, in the browser.

Comment: So I understand that the method is returning null. But I don't understand why it isn't returning a new `DataSource`. I don't understand what you mean by wrapping the IOException into a runtime exception. I'm new to error handling.

Comment: It returns null because an IOException is thrown. You chose to catch this exception, print it to some place where it goes unnoticed, and return null. Replace `e.printStackTrace();` with `throw new IllegalStateException(e);`, and instead of getting an obscure null value, you'll have a clear exception telling you what is wrong and where.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, I including the file structure in my question. Where should the db.properties file be? I assumed the `WEB-INF` directory was the most suitable location?

Comment: It's one of the appropriate locations, but you won't be able to read a resource from inside the war's WEB-INF directory using `new FileInputStream("db.properties");`. This looks for the file in the current directory of the JVM, i.e. the directory from which the `java` command starting tomcat was executed. If you want to read it from WEB-INF, use http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29.

Answer (score 2):

```
fis = new FileInputStream("db.properties");
```

This line is throwing a `FileNotFoundException`. You are catching the exception and returning a null value in `return mysqlDS;`

So the `DataSource dd` is null and when you access it, a null pointer exception is thrown.

You need to ensure that the db.properties is readable from your java program. Either with a full path or by ensuring that it is part of a jar where it can be located by the class loader.

Comment: I added a picture of the file structure, where should the db.properties file be located?